# Is there any way (event in VBA) to know when the tab order is manually changed?

Tags: excel, vba

I have a workbook with 15 tabs.
Is there any way to know when the tab order is manually changed?

For example, the current scenario:
**TAB 1 | TAB 2 | TAB 3 | TAB 4 | TAB 5 | TAB 6 |...**

If the user manually change the order of the tabs for:
**TAB 6 | TAB 2 | TAB 3 | TAB 4 | TAB 5 | TAB 1 |...**

is there any event that captures this moment?
If someone adds a new Tab I can use:
*Private Sub Workbook_NewSheet(ByVal Sh As Object)*

And for the change in order?

**The reason is**: there is a set of buttons, like a menu bar, following the order of the tabs. If someone changes the order, the tool needs to update the order of the buttons.

*PS: I cannot lock/protect the workbook.*

Tks

Comment: Why not explicitly reference the worksheets, instead of their relative position?

Comment: This sounds like an XY problem (https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Can you explain exactly what the issue is? There may be a better solution, along the lines @Luuklag alludes to.

Comment: @Luuklag I think that's covered in the paragraph "The reason is: ...". The OP wants to dynamically update the "menu bar" (whatever it is) to match the order of the worksheets.

Comment: There are 2 things that we need to consider here. **[1.]** Sheet1 is active and you move this sheet. This cannot be captured. **[2.]** Sheet1 is active and you move say Sheet2. This can be captured using the `Private Sub Workbook_SheetDeactivate(ByVal Sh As Object)`

Comment: **[3.]** Workaround: Save the sheet tab order in a hidden sheet. In `Private Sub Workbook_SheetSelectionChange(ByVal Sh As Object, ByVal Target As Range)` and `Private Sub Workbook_BeforeClose(Cancel As Boolean)` check if the order of the sheets is same.

Comment: @CindyMeister I know what the reason is, that is why I commented. Instead of referencing the relative sheet positions in his button codes, he should use an explicit reference. Which would make capturing any change in order irrelevant.

Comment: Denny, I agree with @Luuklag. If you are referencing the sheet position then your code could behave unexpectedly. Use `Code Names` to work with them.

Comment: When you drag a sheet, it becomes active, which means the menu sheet deactivates. So don't track the order of sheets, just regenerate the menu from the menu sheet's `Worksheet_Activate` each time.

Comment: `Workbook_SheetDeactivate` It's as close as I could get. But I'm concerned about the performance since if the user changes tabs several times just to consult something, there may be a delay due to menu ordering (they are 15 to 20 tabs).

I don't know how many times the user would do this, and I wouldn't want to create a "Refresh Menu" button for that. The idea is, only when the user moves the tabs, the menu will be rearranged.

`Worksheet_Activate` and `Workbook_SheetDeactivate` will be called every time the user flips to another tab.

Comment: @DennysLopes what prevents you from explicitly referencing worksheets by name, rather then by index?

Comment: The problem is not how to call the sheets. And to be honest I know it does not make sense .. but it is a client needed. We have a menu bar on the top of the tool. Each button calls one tab and it works properly regardless of the order of the tabs. I had done the menu following the order of the tabs just to make easier for the user. The point is, for some reason, the client requested this magical item. If he changes the order of the tabs (put the TAB 1 in the last), he would like to see the button (in menu bar) in the last as well.

Comment: If calculation is set to automatic, the `Worksheet_Calculate` event is triggered if the sheet is moved manually. You can check the order each time the event is triggered.

Comment: To limit the amount of checking, create a hidden sheet and call the `SHEET` function within the hidden sheet for each other sheet. Then just check the recalculation in the hidden sheet.